# Example of a maximally linearly independent subset of an infinite-dimensional vector space that does not form a basis

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, vector-spaces

A few weeks ago our professor for linear algebra mentioned that from the maximal linear independence property the basis property of a subset of a vector space can only be deduced of the vector space is finite-dimensional.

Can you give an example of a subset in an infinite-dimensional vector space with the maximal linear independence property that is not a basis of said vector space?

I am only fond of concepts up to real analysis 2. So, if possible, I‘d be glad if you could exclude examples from topology and such.

Thank you a lot in advance!

Comment: There is no such example.

Comment: Indeed, you should clarify your definition of [maximal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximal_and_minimal_elements), as with the usual one any maximal linearly independent subset is a basis, [also in an infinite dimensional vector space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basis_(linear_algebra)#Properties).

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. By maximal linear independence I refer to that if you were to add any further element of the vector space to the subset it wouldn’t be linearly independent anymore. Is what I claimed to have heard my professor saying incorrect?

Comment: Follow up clarification: in the scope of our lectures we defined a linear combination to contain finitely many non-zero coefficients. Is that the problem? If so is it now possible to give an example?